# Stove Insulation - replace or clean after milk boiled over?

Tags: oven, natural-gas, gas-burner

We had a party at my home and someone left hot chocolate on the stove and it boiled over...everywhere. The counters and external of the stove was cleaned off but this morning I removed the top to see if hot chocolate got inside. It did.
[image: Hot chocolate insulation]

I still have to find out if it was actual milk or just a hot water mix. My concern is if it was actual milk and the stink if this is not cleaned up.

So how do I clean this up / fix it? I think that I am going to try this order.

1. Shop vac out the chocolate - spray water in, vac it out, repeat
2. Cut out the bad insulation sections and replace with new
3. Replace the insulation - I would prefer not to disassemble the whole unit to replace the insulation.

Any other suggestions?

**Update on progress.** It's real milk and it is soaked all the way through the insulation to the top of the oven...I think that I am leaning towards replacing the insulation. Now the question is, can I replace the insulation down the sides of the unit?

Comment: Frankly, I'd just wait to see if any odor develops and if so, does it go away. It's been a month now, so that should be enough time to let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Some cleaning can be done before trying to replace the insulation. The biggest risk is using the wrong stuff and setting it on fire.

To clean it, wet it with rubbing alcohol or water (alcohol is better since it evaporates faster and disinfects). Wipe accessible areas clean and soak up the milk in the insulation with a towel. Repeat as you see fit to get it out of the insulation. Since alcohol is flammable, you'll need to make sure it is completely dry. Give it 2-3 hours and that's more than enough due to the evaporative nature of rubbing alcohol.

After drying, there really isn't a whole lot needed to be done. Bacterial won't be growing in the dried out insulation and the stain isn't going to affect it a whole lot.

Answer (score -1):

The smell that will be coming is from bacteria, the best and safest solution is to replace the stove. If you replace the insulation be sure to use the proper type. Be sure it did not saturate the insulation on the side or bottom of the oven. I do not know your skill set but consider hiring a professional to replace the insulation. It is also possible your homeowners insurance will cover the cost of repair or replacement, you will not know until you contact them.

Comment: Replace the entire stove to fix a bit of spilt milk? Should he cry over it, too?